# How can I convert decimal? to string?

Tags: c#

I'm writing an ASP.NET MVC program in C# and I have a date fetched from my database, but the date is set as a decimal type, and I can't change that. I need to know how I can format the decimal to look like `04/15/2017` instead of `20170415.00`

This is how that column is declared in my model.

```
public decimal? SIM2_DUE_DATE { get; set; }
```

I'm calling the date from the database. I have over 1000 dates that need to be formatted. I just used that one as an example, so I can't format it specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by using `DateTime.ParseExact`:

```
string dueDate = SIM2_DUE_DATE.ToString("D"); // remove decimals
var parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dueDate, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // parse the date and ensure it's in that specific format
var display = parsedDate.ToShortDateString(); // get the culture-specific date representation
```

Notice that this would fail if you kept the decimals

Answer (score 5):

You can use math to convert your "date" to `DateTime` type. First spilt it into parts like this:

```
var date = 20170415.00M;
var year = (int)date / 10000;
var month = (int) date / 100 % 100;
var day = (int)date % 100;
```

then call a `DateTime` constructor:

```
var dateTime = new DateTime(year, month, day);
```

Comment: He doesn't need a DateTime type, so he would add .ToString() to your final call.

Comment: This can be done by `dateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your date in decimal value

```
decimal dtdec = 20170415.00M;
```

You have few options

```
                var newDate = DateTime.ParseExact(((Int64)dtdec).ToString(),
                                      "yyyyMMdd",
                                       System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(newDate.ToShortDateString());
```

Or

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse(dtdec.ToString("####/##/##")));
```

Or

```
Console.WriteLine(dtdec.ToString("####/##/##"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Decimal decimalDateValue = 20170105.00;
DateTime dateEquivalent = DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime.TryParse(decimalDateValue.ToString(),out dateEquivalent);
```